# Cut out first part of animation

Tags: animation, keyframes

I am trying to import a motion capture clip but the first 250 frames are irrelevant to the desired animation. Even though I can get the timeline to show the desired key frames, the fbx file I export still contains the whole animation with the part I don’t want at the beginning.

Is there a way to edit or simply delete the first part?

Comment: you could just render it out and then shorten with the vse editor

Comment: Did you try to delete the unwanted keyframes by selecting them and press the delete button?

Comment: The animation is brought in from motion capture. I’m a bit new to blender and couldn’t really find anything straight forward. There are a load of keyframes, but will try that method! Thank you